# Duplicated attributes in the decorator pattern

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I intend to use the decorator pattern, and I'm wondering about attribute duplication...I mean, if the base class (the one being decorated) has a lot of state (attributes, properties or whatever), when you use the decorator pattern, you always end up with two copies of that state, right? (the one in the decorating class, and the one in the decorated one) Is that always so?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104642/abstract-base-class-should-have-or-not-have-data-members-when-using-decorator-pa) a similar questions is "kind of" asked, but the replies didn't make it clearer to me.

Also in the book "Head First: Design Patterns", they don't mention anything of this sort as a disadvantage of the pattern.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

For me a decorator does not need to store a state, eg: if class `A` have a method `getTotal()`, then `DecoratorA::getTotal()` might return `2*A::getTotal()`.

The decorator can lazily return data based on the object it decorate. It may have some attribute (like the `2` in my example), but it is basically delegation with some pre/post processing.

You would store it eventually if the cost is too high (like some cache) but I wonder what the use for such a decorator if each attribute need to be stored. It would be quicker to return a new instance of decorated object, with attributes based on a some computation.

Comment: Yes, I agree the decorator doesn't need to store state...but since it is also an instance of the decorated object [see, e.g., the Wikipedia diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#mediaviewer/File:Decorator_UML_class_diagram.svg), it automatically has all the attributes of the decorated objects (although, maybe it doesn't need them or want them)

Comment: Yes. Depends also if you use interface or abstraction. And if you do inheritance for your decorator, then probably you should create a new object based on another - say a decorator with a constant state that would not change even if decorated object change - but I would not call that a decorator.